# Can hat data be accessed through the API?

Tags: support, winter-bash

Is there a way to access Winter Bash hat data through the [Data Explorer API](https://data.stackexchange.com/)? If there is, will it still be accessible after the hats are put back in their boxes?

Comment: Pfft. We demand a **separate** Hats API !!!!! Get to work, Stack Exchange.

Comment: cross site dupe? http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/245868/158100 and a better one: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/159916/158100

Comment: We need a SEHE: A Stack Exchange Hats Explorer

Comment: Through api, yes (there's special WB api, can't get some examples as using mobile). Through Data SE, no.

Comment: Replace 2014 with 2015 and it'd work. http://stackapps.com/questions/5048/how-to-get-data-related-to-winter-bash

Comment: @Pekka웃 It already exists! https://xkcd.com/1481/